# How to start, stop and re-start cluster manually in Bluemix Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, ibm-cloud

What is the simplest way to start and stop Spark clusters manually in Bluemix? I would basically want to run the same things that

```
sbin/start-all.sh
```

and

```
sbin/stop-all.sh
```

do on a standalone Spark installment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. The Apache Spark service in Bluemix runs clusters that are shared by many users. No user is allowed to shut down or start these clusters.

Comment: Ok. So if I understand correctly, the only way to restart an application is to upload it via spark-submit, right?

Comment: I'm not familiar with spark-submit, only with the notebooks. They use the same Spark clusters.

If you're looking for ways to restart your application, consider asking a new question.